# Is the problem of finding the "all-terminal connectivity polynomial" polynomially bounded?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I want to proof whether the problem of finding the "all-terminal connectivity polynomial" of a given graph G(V,E) is checkable in a polynomial time. In order to do so I should first proof that it is polynomially bounded, i.e $|y| < p(|x|)$. 
In this case I guess that $|x| \text{~} n^2$
but I am not sure about $|y|$ .

**Note - Definition**
For a given graph $G(V, E)$ each edge $E_{ij}$ has a $p_{ij}$-probability of being reliable and $(1 - p_{ij})$ probability of failure. Considering that each edge fails independently and nodes are perfectly reliable, the function

$Rel(G)$ = $Pr[$ for each pair of nodes $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ there exists at least one reliable path between them $]$

is called all-terminal connectivity (or reliability) function of the network.

Comment: 1. you should define the problem or link to a definition. 2. This smells like homework; if not, can you clarify where it comes from ?

Comment: @Suresh The fact is that finding "all-terminal connectivity polynomial" is known to be a NP-hard problem. What I want to proof here is that it is also hard to check whether a given solution is correct or not (what would make this problem hard to check and hard to find)...don't know if it is enough clear

Comment: then at the very least please define the problem in the question.

Comment: I have never heard of “all-terminal connectivity polynomial.”  What is it?  In other words, as Suresh said, please define the problem.

Comment: For a given graph G(V, E) each edge Eij has a pij-probability of being reliable and (1 - pij) probability of failure. Considering that each edge fails independently and nodes are perfectly reliable, the function Rel(G) = Pr[for each pair of nodes xi and xj there exists at least one reliable path between them] is called all-terminal connectivity (or reliability) function of the network.

Comment: Presumably you know that the problem is #P-complete ? http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=225069 and that there's an FPRAS for 1-Rel(G) = Fail(G) ?

Comment: Yes I know that resolving the problem is #P-complete, what I want to find out is : "is it easy (does exist any polynomial algorithm) that for a given solution to check whether it is correct or not?"

Comment: 1. I'd recommend you add the reference to the #P-completeness into the question, as well as the related paper, just so a reader has the full background. 2. While this is not a formal statement, it seems to me that it would be highly unlikely for a #P-complete problem to have a short proof.

Comment: @Suresh: Wouldn't a short proof for this give FNP=#P? This would partially collapse the polynomial hierarchy, making it extremely unlikely.

Comment: that's my suspicion, but I didn't have a formal argument for it. It would go something like $PH \subseteq P^{#P} = P^{FNP} = \Pi_2$ or something like that.

Comment: Well, depending on exactly what is meant by a proof in this context it may mean TFNP=#P, which similarly partially collapse the hierarchy. Obviously, $\Pi_2 \subseteq PH$, which finishes the circle giving $\Pi_2 = PH$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll convert my comment to an answer.

The problem of computing the Rel(G) is #P-Complete ([see this paper by Karger](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=225069)), and there's also an FPRAS for 1-Rel(G) (also in the Karger paper). Note that if you could verify whether Rel(G) was less than any fixed number $k$, then you could binary search for an approximate solution for Rel(G) that would run in P-time, which seems a little unlikely.